# Call to a REST API cause 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angularjs, http

Am trying to integrate a service with my web app, what i did is making post call but I got this Error:

```
POST https://admin.example.com/api/v1/service 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Am not so good with HTTP codes i tried to figure out what 415 means I didn't reall get it but what am doing is really simple:

```
.controller('createBeaconCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {
    $scope.item = {
      value1: $scope.value1,
      value2: $scope.value2,
      value3: 1
    };
    var url = 'https://admin.example.com/api/v1/service';
    $scope.submit = function() {
      $http.post(url, $scope.item).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        console.log("Done");
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log("Error making the call");
      });
    };
  });
```

Am authenticating my call by sending the username and the password to the header:

```
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {
    username: 'e9fbcaf4edsfdisfhsdhfds',
    password: 'fdsfGFGREER4'
  };
```

i checked the `header` the `username` and `password` there and the the values of the `$scope.item` in the payload.

I also have another two enquiries first i think it's not secure to hard code my username and password what is the proper way to do it? also i had CORS problem but i turned off the chrome security to get rid of it because if the APIs meant to be called from different domains why i got CORS Error.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't have to be too good with HTTP codes to google HTTP code 415.

Comment: $.post probably set content type to application/x-www-url-encoded. You need application/json.

Comment: Does the REST API accepts JSON? Because that's what $http sends by default.

Comment: true, stupid question sorry, i did this $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'; i got bad request now but, yeah the first error gone

Answer (score 1):

Posting using AngularJS does not automatically infer the 'application/json' header which will tell the server at admin.example.com to parse the data as JSON. The 415 indicates that the server is expecting JSON data and currently it is set as something unknown. Try something a bit like this:

`$http({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'https://admin.example.com/api/v1/service',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
});`

Found on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Err, the documentation says: *The $http service will automatically add certain HTTP headers to all requests. [...] $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post: (header defaults for POST requests)
    Content-Type: application/json*